# Two similar proofs that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\mu}={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$, which one is correct?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, mathematical-physics, tensors, kronecker-delta

> Using the chain rule, show that the derivative transforms as
> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\to\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\mu}={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}\tag{A}$$

This is the way I would do this, firstly, by the chain rule
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\mu}=\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^\nu}\tag{1}$$
and noting that contravariant vectors transform as $x^\mu \to x'^\mu={\Lambda^\mu}_\nu x^\nu$,
then the inverse Lorentz transformation for contravariant vectors is
$x^\mu={\Lambda_\nu}^\mu x'^\nu$. Relabelling $\mu \to \nu$ and $\nu \to \mu$, then this inverse Lorentz transform can be written as $x^\nu={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu x'^\mu$.
Then $$\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu}=\frac{\partial\left({\Lambda_\mu}^\nu x'^\mu\right)}{\partial x'^\mu}\stackrel{\color{red}{?}}={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu\frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x'^\mu}={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu\times 1\tag{2}$$
now by direct substitution into $(1)$, the result, $(\mathrm{A})$ follows immediately. I put a red question mark over the part of my proof for which I am unsure about. Since I am assuming the $4\times 4$ boost matrix, ${\Lambda_\mu}^\nu$ is constant as far as the differentiation is concerned.

---

Now, the proof given by the author is almost identical to mine, (except for one small change which I don't fully understand the need for):

> The chain rule gives $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\mu}=\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^\nu}$$
> Using $x^\nu={\Lambda_\rho}^\nu x'^\rho$
> $$\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\mu}{\Lambda_\rho}^\nu x'^\rho\quad{\color{blue}{=}}\quad{\Lambda_\rho}^\nu\delta_\mu^\rho={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu\tag{3}$$
> So $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\mu}={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$$

---

Where I note that after blue equality in eqn. $(3)$ the author has used the fact that $$\frac{\partial x'^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta_\mu^\rho \tag{4}$$

But why did the author need to use $(4)$? This makes me believe that the manipulation I used after the question-marked equality for eqn. $(2)$ is not valid. Put another way, is differentiating wrt. to a set of coordinates, $x'^\mu$, in a new (primed) frame legitimate?

Comment: I apologize that the horizontal spacing between the indices for the Lorentz boost matrices is too large as I had to use `\quad` as I cannot seem to get `\,` and `\;` as described in the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/15077#15077) to render correctly.

Comment: A better way to typeset indices of tensor expressions is like this: `Lambda_\mu {}^\nu` will render to $\Lambda_\mu {}^\nu$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu}=\frac{\partial\left({\Lambda_\mu}^\nu x'^\mu\right)}{\partial x'^\mu}\stackrel{\color{red}{?}}={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu\frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x'^\mu}={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu\times 1\tag{2}$$

Unfortunately, there are two mistakes in this equation.

First mistake, this expression
$$\frac{\partial\left({\Lambda_\mu}^\nu x'^\mu\right)}{\partial x'^\mu}$$
is wrong, because the index $\mu$ appears three times. You should have changed $\mu$ to another letter, say, $\rho$. Thus, you would obtain
$$\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu}=\frac{\partial\left({\Lambda_\rho}^\nu x'^\rho\right)}{\partial x'^\mu}={\Lambda_\rho}^\nu\frac{\partial x'^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu}$$

Second mistake, this expression
$$\frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x'^\mu}=1$$
is wrong. The correct result is
$$\frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x'^\mu}=\frac{\partial x'^0}{\partial x'^0}+\frac{\partial x'^1}{\partial x'^1}+\frac{\partial x'^2}{\partial x'^2}+\frac{\partial x'^3}{\partial x'^3}=4,$$
because the convention that repeated indices imply the summation is to be done.

> But why did the author need to use $(4)$?

Because $x'^0,x'^1,x'^2,x'^3$ are independent variables. Thus, for example,
$$\frac{\partial x'^0}{\partial x'^0}=1 \ ; \frac{\partial x'^0}{\partial x'^1}=0; \frac{\partial x'^0}{\partial x'^2}=0; \frac{\partial x'^0}{\partial x'^3}=0,$$
and so on. Therefore,
$$\frac{\partial x'^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta^\rho_\mu=\begin{cases}1, \text{if} \ \ \rho=\mu\\0, \text{if} \ \ \rho\ne\mu\end{cases}$$
is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in the last expression for the case that $\rho=\mu$, did you mean $4$ instead of $1$? As $\delta_\mu^\mu=4$ due to the summation convention? Thank you also for editing my question, looks much better now.

Comment: @SiriusBlack My last equation is correct. For example, if $\rho=1$ and $\mu=2$, then $\displaystyle\frac{\partial x^{\prime 1}}{\partial x^{\prime 2}}=0$. If $\rho=3$ and $\mu=3$, then $\displaystyle\frac{\partial x^{\prime 3}}{\partial x^{\prime 3}}=1$. However, if $\rho=\mu$, then $\displaystyle\frac{\partial x^{\prime \mu}}{\partial x^{\prime \mu}}=\delta^\mu_\mu=\delta^0_0+\delta^1_1+\delta^2_2+\delta^3_3=4$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand you, it's a subtlety, like an 'if....then' type logical statement where the order matters. So if $\rho=\mu$ *then* $\delta^\mu_\mu=4$, but if $\delta_\mu^\rho=1$ _then_  $\rho=\mu$. That's my interpretation anyway, or maybe I'm just overthinking it.

Comment: @SiriusBlack What you have wrote does not makes sense to me. As far as I know, the statement "if $p$, then $q$" is the same as "$q$, if $p$".

Comment: @SiriusBlack Let $M$ be a matrix $4\times 4$ whose entries are $\displaystyle\frac{\partial x'^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu}$ and $I$ be the identity matrix $4\times4$ whose entries are $\delta^\rho_\mu$. Then the equation $$\frac{\partial x'^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta^\rho_\mu$$ means that $$M=I.$$

Comment: @SiriusBlack If $M=I$, then $\operatorname{Tr}(M)=\operatorname{Tr}(I)=4$, where $\operatorname{Tr}$ is the trace. This means that if $$\frac{\partial x'^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta^\rho_\mu$$, then  $$\frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta^\mu_\mu=4.$$

Comment: @SiriusBlack If you are satisfied with my answer, please accept it by clicking on the check-mark on the left of the answer.

Comment: That I will, I just would like to read this answer/comments a bit more first to try to understand it better if that's okay?  Don't worry, I have never left a question I asked with an answer unaccepted. As this $\delta_\mu^\mu=1 \quad \text{or} \quad 4 \quad$ is quite confusing, as one could argue that the upper statement in the last expression of your answer;  $\delta^\rho_\mu=1 \quad \text{if} \quad \rho=\mu\quad$ actually means we have $\delta_\mu^\mu$ and as you've said, that is equal to $4$ (and _not_ $1$) due to the repeated index - Einstein summation convention.

Comment: @SiriusBlack I think now I know why we are confused. Simply taking $\rho=\mu$ in $$(*) \ \ \ \ \ \frac{\partial x'^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta^\rho_\mu$$ is **not** the proper way to obtain $$ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta^\mu_\mu.$$ The proper way is multiplying $(*)$ by $\delta^\mu_\rho$ to obtain $$\delta^\mu_\rho\frac{\partial x'^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta^\mu_\rho\delta^\rho_\mu\implies \frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta^\mu_\mu.$$

Comment: "Simply taking $\rho=\mu$ in $ \dfrac{\partial x'^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta^\rho_\mu$ is **not** the proper way to obtain $\dfrac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta^\mu_\mu.$" But why not? Seems logical to me.

Comment: @SiriusBlack That is embarrassing. Actually, you can set $\rho=\mu$, this is the well-known *contraction* process. Equivalently, we can
also contract a tensor by multiplying by the Kronecker tensor $\delta^\mu_\rho$. Anyway, the discussion has already expanded a lot here in the comments. I end here. Thanks for the thought-provoking discussion.